# How to make SOLR return a CLOB field on search

Tags: solr

Is there anyway to return a CLOB value when searching using Solr? Does someone knows anything about this?

Please let me know if you have any opinion about this that can help me. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

All string fields will return a "CLOB value" (in fact, all fields will, as long as they're set as stored). A string field is suitable for keeping regular character data as you'd expect. In previous versions a StrField could be limited to 32768 bytes, but a TextField should be unlimited. There's a setting that can affect the number of tokens stored, maxFieldLength, but that can be changed to something like  2^31 to be virtually unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

```
<entity name="Description" transformer="ClobTransformer" query="select * from TABLENAME" >

<field column="COLUMNNAME" name="COLUMNNAME" clob="true" sourceColName="COLUMNNAME" />
```

REF :: [ClobTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ClobTransformer)

**It's work with me**